# Ansible not in condition

Tags: ansible

I have a variable called `var1` which has an output like

```yaml
[this is an apple, this is a banana, this is a pineapple]
```

And `var2` as

```yaml
[this is an apple, this is a banana, this is a mango, this is a watermelon, this is a pineapple]
```

I want to check if all the values in `var1` are there in `var2` I am trying to do a when condition and it is not the correct output.

```yaml
 - name: check condition 
   Shell: "echo all values are there" 
   When: var1 in var2
```

Comment: Neither your `var1` nor your `var2` are something valid, please fix this to provide  a [mre]. Then, why do you use a shell to display something? Use a `debug` or an `assert` if you want to fail the play. Third, what you are looking for is [`when: var1 | difference(var2) | length == 0`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory)

Comment: `when: var1 | intersect(var2) | length == var1 | length`

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Check if all items in var1 are also in var2"***

A: Use filter [*difference*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: var1 is a subset of var2
      when: _diff|length == 0
      vars:
        _diff: "{{ var1|difference(var2) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: var1 is a subset of var2
```

To test the negative case add elements *'x'* and *'y'* to *var1*. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Items {{ _diff }} of var1 are missing in var2"
      when: _diff|length != 0
      vars:
        var1: [x, y, this is an apple, this is a banana, this is a pineapple]
        _diff: "{{ var1|difference(var2) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Items ['x', 'y'] of var1 are missing in var2
```